# NX: How can I use run-many to run multiple targets?

Tags: lint, monorepo, typechecking, nrwl-nx, nrwl

At present, I run:

`npx nx run-many --all --skip-nx-cache --parallel --target lint` to lint all my projects.

But, I would like to run lint and type-check. Something like:

`npx nx run-many --all --skip-nx-cache --parallel --target lint type-check`

But, the above command runs the target `lint` and considers type-check as an additional flag.

I tried:

1. `npx nx run-many --all --skip-nx-cache --parallel --target=lint,type-check`
2. `npx nx run-many --all --skip-nx-cache --parallel --targets=lint,type-check`

None worked. Are there any flags I am missing to run multiple targets or do I have to do it separately?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use the run many to indicate the multiple targets:

`npx nx run-many --all --skip-nx-cache --parallel --targets=lint,type-check`

It also can be written like

`npx nx run-many --all --skip-nx-cache --parallel -t lint type-check`

Here are the docs: https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/run-many#examples